# Why is my graphic not showing up on my p5js project w/ Mapbox API

Tags: javascript, mapbox, p5.js

I'm trying to visualize data by mapping the latitude, longitude, and magnitude of some major Chicago neighborhoods with p5.js. It's inspired by [this coding challenge](https://youtu.be/ZiYdOwOrGyc). I followed it thoroughly, only changed the area and zoom of the map (using Mapbox API). The codes look right, and the map shows up. But when I try to visualize just one single location as a circle on the map before even inputting the data, it doesn't show up on the sketch.
Super grateful if anyone can let me know what might be the problem here!

```js
var mapimg;
var zoom = 10;
var clat = 0;
var clon = 0;
var lat = 41.9000;
var lon = -87.7204;


function preload() {
  mapimg = loadImage ('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v10/static/-87.7278,41.9099,10,0/400x400?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2wzMDcyNCIsImEiOiJja3VuMWNieWgzd3MzMnVrNmU2bzNwdndoIn0.cGgvcAgQwVdnNsHLIeBf9A');
}

  
function mercX(lon) {
  lon = radians(lon);
  var a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
  var b = (lon) + PI;
  return a * b;
}

function mercY (lat) {
  lat = radians(lat);
  var a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
  var b = tan(PI / 4 + lat / 2);
  var c = PI - log(b);
  return a * c;
}
  


function setup() {

  createCanvas(400, 400);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(mapimg, 0, 0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(100);
  noFill();
  circle(0, 0, 500);

  var cx = mercX(clon);
  var cy = mercY(clat);
  var x = mercX(lon) - cx;
  var y = mercY(lat) - cy;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How/where do you actually call these functions? All you've shown is some function declarations, without any example of usage. This code doesn't _do_ anything. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. If that's within a code snippet which will actually run and demonstrate the problem to us, that's even better. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Just edited the question, hopefully it makes sense to you now.

Comment: Kudos for posting your question with a runnable snippet. You are the best for doing this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue has to do with `mercX` and `mercY` and the inputs you are passing to them. It looks like maybe they are designed to convert latitude and longitude into pixels.

You were using `0` for both `clat` and `clon` which would mean that the map was centered on the equator at the prime meridian. So the relative pixel coordinates between there and Chicago were huge. I think I've corrected the code by using values for `clat` and `clon` from your mapbox URL. However, I find the implementations of `mercX` and `mercY` to be somewhat incomprehensible, and I'm not sure what you are trying to highlight, so I cannot be sure. But at least x and y are on screen now (shown with a red point).

```js
var mapimg;
var zoom = 10;
var clat = 41.9099;
var clon = -87.7278;
var lat = 41.9000;
var lon = -87.7204;


function preload() {
  mapimg = loadImage ('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v10/static/-87.7278,41.9099,10,0/400x400?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2wzMDcyNCIsImEiOiJja3VuMWNieWgzd3MzMnVrNmU2bzNwdndoIn0.cGgvcAgQwVdnNsHLIeBf9A');
}

  
function mercX(lon) {
  lon = radians(lon);
  var a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
  var b = (lon) + PI;
  return a * b;
}

function mercY (lat) {
  lat = radians(lat);
  var a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
  var b = tan(PI / 4 + lat / 2);
  var c = PI - log(b);
  return a * c;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(mapimg, 0, 0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(100);
  noFill();
  circle(0, 0, 500);

  // get the center of the image in pixels
  var cx = mercX(clon);
  var cy = mercY(clat);
  // convert lon & lat to pixels and find the relative displacement from the center
  var x = mercX(lon) - cx;
  var y = mercY(lat) - cy;
  
  print({ cx, cy, x, y });
  
  stroke('red');
  strokeWeight(8);
  point(x, y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```